# How to pronounce 绿林?

Tags: pronunciation

The [绿林](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%BClin) were an agrarian rebellion movement during the Xin dynasty. How is 绿林 pronounced?

- Wikipedia <strike>claims</strike>claimed that it's Lǜlín
- But in [dictionaries](http://www.zdic.net/c/f/162/360278.htm) it's lùlín

Which one is right?

Comment: Wikipedia fixed (by you) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be `lùlín`.

[`绿`](http://www.zdic.net/z/21/xs/7EFF.htm) is 多音字(polyphone) in Chinese, `lǜ` is usually used for color, `lù` is used for some 专有名词(proper noun).

[`绿林`](http://www.zdic.net/c/f/162/360278.htm) is pronounced as `lùlín`, because it came from the name of the mountain `绿林山`, which is pronounced as `lùlínshān`.

And `绿林` should be pronounced as `lùlín`, it has become a proper noun, in general it won't be used for the meaning of "green woods".

There are also other examples of `绿` pronounced as `lù`. Such as [`鸭绿江`](http://www.zdic.net/c/d/23/53582.htm), [`绿营`](http://www.zdic.net/c/f/162/360280.htm).

Comment: Actually it does mean green woods. The meaning is the same, as implied in your example 绿营 (green camp/banners).

Comment: @倪阔乐 "Green woods" might be the origination of the name of `绿林山`, might not be, I can't find any reference about it. What I mean is that `绿林` has become a proper noun, when we use it we won't mean "green woods". `绿营` is other issue, it's proper noun too.

Answer (score 4):

Like @songyuanyao said, `lùlín` is the one currently accepted in dictionaries.

绿 and 录 used to share the same pronunciation, somewhat between `lù` and `lǜ` (let's for a moment forget about 入声). Then vowel shifts happen, in different ways and to different degrees in different times and places. Now 绿 and 录 are parted in mandarin, but not in some other dialects.

Historically, for whatever reason, mandarin tried to conform to local and historical pronunciations, that's why we see a lot of strange pronunciation for toponyms.

But this trend is fading. Take 六安 for example, in newer dictionaries, it's read as `liu'an` instead of the traditional `lu'an`. The local people aren't content with this change, but there is nothing special with this 六; `lu` is just a local pronunciation, keeping it makes no sense. If we keep every local pronunciation, mandarin will explode with polyphones.

Same case with 绿 in 绿林 etc. Whatever the context, 绿 is unmistakably color of the chlorophyll. Keeping two pronunciations will do no good but only confuse people and raise questions like this. If `lù` is one day erased from dictionaries, I wouldn't be surprised a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

well, after the moment of forgetting 入聲, may we try the  approach by cantonese, which still has 入聲, and, is highly correlated to middle chinese (中古漢語)?

[綠 (u+7da0)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%B6%A0) in cantonese has only **one** pronunciation, which is luk6 (sydney lay scheme), [sound file](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/sound/luk6.Mp3)

說文解字 explained 綠 is "从糸﹒彔聲﹒力玉切"; that [彔 (u+5f54)](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%BD%94) is also luk6 in cantonese.

then, 力玉切:

[力](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%8A%9B) --> lik6, get "l"

[玉](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%8E%89) --> yuk6, get uk6

combine the "l" from "力" & "uk6" from "玉", we get **luk6**. the pronunciation in cantonese today, still matches what was written in 漢 dynasty, about 1900+ years ago. isn't it wonderful?

btw, [六](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E5%85%AD) also shares the same pronunciation (exact initial, final & tone) with 綠.

imo, discrepancy between modern days mandarin and literatures of yore,  rhyme dictionaries (韻書) are unsolvable; which causes confusions.

then, particular pronunciations would disappear, well, very unlikely. i would suggest, in case of doubt, shift to other dialects, lookup rhyme dictionaries; and adjust accordingly.